# Cant get this code to run in browser using firefox

Tags: javascript, function, loops

trying to get this code to run in broser i saved it and when i try to open it nothing happens i can't see the prompt up box any help would be appreciated thanks. Im using a switch to try to get a prompt to pop up

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var secretNumber = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 5:", "");
secretNumber = parseInt(secretNumber);

switch (secretNumber)
{
case 1:
    document.write("Too low!");
    break;

case 2:
    document.write("Too low!");
    break;

case 3
    document.write("You guessed the secret number!");
    break;

case 4
    document.write("Too high!");
    break;

case 5 
    document.write("Too high!");
    break;

default:
    document.write("you did not enter a number between 1 and 5!");
    break;
}
document.write("<br />Execution continues here");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `:` character from your switch in cases 3-5. Here's the working code:

```
var secretNumber = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 5:", "");
secretNumber = parseInt(secretNumber);

switch (secretNumber)
{
case 1:
    document.write("Too low!");
    break;

case 2:
    document.write("Too low!");
    break;

case 3:
    document.write("You guessed the secret number!");
    break;

case 4:
    document.write("Too high!");
    break;

case 5:
    document.write("Too high!");
    break;

default:
    document.write("you did not enter a number between 1 and 5!");
    break;
}
document.write("<br />Execution continues here");
```